# Why did Expelliarmus not knock the prophecy out of Harry's hand?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Neville used the disarming charm on Harry in the Department of Mysteries.

> Harry launched himself across the floor and grabbed the Death Eater around the knees, causing him to topple and his aim to go awry. Neville overturned a desk in his anxiety to help; and pointing his wand wildly at the struggling pair, he cried:
>
> 'EXPELLIARMUS!'
>
> Both Harry's and the Death Eater's wands flew out of their hands and soared back towards the entrance to the Hall of Prophecy

**Why did the spell not disarm Harry completely as he was also holding the prophecy in the other hand?**

According to the wiki: **The Disarming Charm (Expelliarmus) was a charm that forced whatever an opponent was holding to fly out of their hand.**

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115185/expelliarmus-inconsistency

Comment: And also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15272/can-expelliarmus-be-used-for-weapons-other-than-wands

Comment: Maybe Neville had specific intentions, or maybe his aim was off. Because certain spells have different uses, and the spells are sent through the wand . . . the wand sort of processes the owner's thoughts? But I think after so much DA, Neville's aim should be pretty good. :)